# Downloading attachments from unseen messages

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I work on university project in **java**. I have to download attachments from new emails using **GMAIL API**.

I successfully connected to gmail account using **OAuth 2.0** authorization.

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY);
```

I tried to get unseen mails using

```
ListMessagesResponse listMessageResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("is:unseen").execute();
```

**listMessageResponse** is not **null** but when I call method **.getResultSizeEstimate()** it returns **0**
also I tried to convert **listMessageResponse** to **List < Message >** (I guess this is more usable) using

```
List<Message> list = listMessageResponse.getMessages();
```

But  **list** launches **NullPointerException**

Then tried to get each attachment with

```
for(Message m : list) {
            List<MessagePart> part = m.getPayload().getParts();
            for(MessagePart p: part) {
                if(p.getFilename()!=null && p.getFilename().length()>0) {
                    System.out.println(p.getFilename()); // Just to check attachment filename
                }
            }
        }
```

Is my approach correct (if not how to fix it) and how should I download those attachments.

**EDIT 1:**

Fixed **q** parameter, I mistakenly wrote **is:unseen** instead of **is:unread**.
Now app reaches unread mails successfully.
(For example there was two unread mails and both successfully reached, I can get theirs IDs easy).

Now this part trows **NullPointerException**

```
List<MessagePart> part = m.getPayload().getParts();
```

Both messages have attachments and **m** is not **null** (I get ID with **.getID()**)

Any ideas how to overcome this and download attachment?

**EDIT 2:**

Attachments Downloading part

```
for(MessagePart p : parts) {

            if ((p.getFilename() != null && p.getFilename().length() > 0)) {
                String filename = p.getFilename();
                String attId = p.getBody().getAttachmentId();
                MessagePartBody attachPart;
                FileOutputStream fileOutFile = null;
                try { 
                   attachPart = service.users().messages().attachments().get("me", p.getPartId(), attId).execute();
                   byte[] fileByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(attachPart.getData());


                   fileOutFile = new FileOutputStream(filename); // Or any other dir
                   fileOutFile.write(fileByteArray);
                   fileOutFile.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO Exception processing attachment: " + filename);
                } finally {
                   if (fileOutFile != null) {
                      try {
                         fileOutFile.close();
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                         // probably doesn't matter
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
```

Downloading working like charm, tested app with different type of emails.
Only thing left is to change label of unread message (that was reached by app) to read. Any tips how to do it?

And one tiny question:
I want this app to fetch mails on every 10 minutes using TimerTask abstract class. Is there need for manual "closing" of connection with gmail or that's done automatically after run() method iteration ends?

```
 @Override
 public void run(){

 // Some fancy code

 service.close(); // Something like that if even exists
 }
```

Comment: You have a custom label called unseen?   Remember Response wont be null its always going to return you a response object.  how ever it sounds like there are no results for your custom label.

Comment: I made silly mistake there I wanted to write unread but wrote unseen.

Comment: @BogosavCvetkovic I updated my answer accordingly, please let me know whether that works for you.

Comment: @BogosavCvetkovic Since your original question got solved, I'd suggest to post a new question with your current problem, and please consider accepting the answer I provided, since that's fundamental to sharing knowledge between users in SO. Also, of course, before posting a new question, please do some research on the subject of changing labels, and only post a question if you encounter problems you cannot solve.

Comment: [Users.messages: modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) and [Class Gmail.Users.Messages.Modify](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Messages.Modify.html) could be good places to start your research on label changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `ListMessagesResponse` ever becomes null. Even if there are no messages that match your query, at least `resultSizeEstimate` will get populated in the resulting response: see [Users.messages: list > Response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#response).

I think you are using the correct approach, just that there is no message that matches your query. Actually, I never saw `is:unseen` before. Did you mean `is:unread` instead?

#### Update:

When using [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) only the `id` and the `threadId` of each message is populated, so you cannot access the message `payload`. In order to get the full message resource, you have to use `Users.messages: get` instead, as you can see in the referenced link:

> Note that each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the [messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method.

So in this case, after getting the list of messages, you have to iterate through the list, and do the following for each message in the list:

- Get the message `id` via [m.getId()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/Message.html#getId--).
- Once you have retrieved the message `id`, use it to call [Gmail.Users.Messages.Get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Messages.Get.html) and get the full message resource. The retrieved message should have all fields populated, including payload, and you should be able to access the corresponding attachments.

#### Code sample:

```java
List<Message> list = listMessageResponse.getMessages();
for(Message m : list) {
  Message message = service.users().messages().get(user, m.getId()).execute();
  List<MessagePart> part = message.getPayload().getParts();
  // Rest of code
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class ListMessagesResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/ListMessagesResponse.html)
- [Users.messages: list > Response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#response)

Comment: You are right, I made mistake with is:unseen. I will edit question with more new details.

Comment: Finally done it, now only left to change message label from unread to read (don't want to read same message more then once). Question edited with the latest info.